# Background image fill up/down in CSS

Tags: css

there is this background-image i have in my div element and I want it to "fill" upwards/downwards and cover its entire height and width. Please explain me how this is possible with CSS. Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `background-position: cover; background-size: 100%;`. Please do some research next time.

Comment: Post your code what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

*Documentation* from CSS Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Thanks a lot wildandjam, it works fine for filling "up" how about the same effect for filling the background image downwards. Thanks again.

Comment: You'd have to make your div (or whatever element you want the background added to), 100% height. To do this, you may have to change your position attribute to fixed or absolute.

So try adding:
`position:fixed;height:100%;width:100%;`